# How to fix package.json to properly run my react app?

Tags: npm, react-router, create-react-app, npm-start

I'm having trouble launching my React App. I get the same message:

> "npm ERR! missing script: start"

but I do have start in my `package.json`.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure? On your screenshot I see that `package.json` has unsaved changes. Maybe you added `start` but didn't save the file yet?

Comment: Images of text should be augmented by the text they contain or replaced with it. This is because images are not searchable, nor are they accessible, and someone trying to help you can't copy the text from them.

Comment: Thank you guys. Fixed.